# EC2 Network Interface with secondary Private IP, not showing on Interface in Windows

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a windows server 2012 r2 instance on EC2 under VPC, I have two Network Interfaces. The Primary Private IP is shown in windows for both. I have a secondary IP address on one of the network interfaces, This secondary IP does not seem to be bound to the interface. The Interface with 10.0.0.186 should also have 10.0.0.254

Am I missing something?

C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ec2.internal
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7cbf:137f:14ce:133d%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.135
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ec2.internal
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9043:dee7:59e6:6649%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.186
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.ec2.internal:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ec2.internal

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:4d9:1d21:cbff:57ff
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4d9:1d21:cbff:57ff%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetIPAddress

```
IPAddress         : fe80::7cbf:137f:14ce:133d%15
InterfaceIndex    : 15
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet 2
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 64
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : fe80::9043:dee7:59e6:6649%12
InterfaceIndex    : 12
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 64
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : fe80::4d9:1d21:cbff:57ff%13
InterfaceIndex    : 13
InterfaceAlias    : Local Area Connection* 12
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 64
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:4d9:1d21:cbff:57ff
InterfaceIndex    : 13
InterfaceAlias    : Local Area Connection* 12
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 64
PrefixOrigin      : RouterAdvertisement
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : fe80::5efe:10.0.0.186%14
InterfaceIndex    : 14
InterfaceAlias    : isatap.ec2.internal
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 128
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Deprecated
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : fe80::5efe:10.0.0.135%14
InterfaceIndex    : 14
InterfaceAlias    : isatap.ec2.internal
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 128
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : Link
AddressState      : Deprecated
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : ::1
InterfaceIndex    : 1
InterfaceAlias    : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
AddressFamily     : IPv6
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 128
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : WellKnown
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : 10.0.0.135
InterfaceIndex    : 15
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet 2
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 24
PrefixOrigin      : Dhcp
SuffixOrigin      : Dhcp
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : 00:57:59
PreferredLifetime : 00:57:59
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : 10.0.0.186
InterfaceIndex    : 12
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 24
PrefixOrigin      : Dhcp
SuffixOrigin      : Dhcp
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : 00:57:59
PreferredLifetime : 00:57:59
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : 127.0.0.1
InterfaceIndex    : 1
InterfaceAlias    : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 8
PrefixOrigin      : WellKnown
SuffixOrigin      : WellKnown
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore
```

Comment: Try `Get-NetIPAddress`. ipconfig does not show all ip addresses.

Comment: added Get-NetIPAddress output which shows the same IPs and the lack of 10.0.0.254. the bottom line is connections on that ip are not getting to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address is not bound to your interface. You can add the address via PowerShell with this:

```
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceIndex 12 –IPAddress 10.0.0.254 -PrefixLength 24
```

Comment: I stated that it was not bound to my interface in the question. the ips are assigned by amazon via dhcp, the question is more why is it not there? if I add an ip, I have to also add the primary IP, and doing it manually for all my servers does not seem like the best solution.

Comment: Because DHCP for IPv4 does only assign **one** IP address per Interface. If you need multiple IP addresses on one interface, you need to manage them manually.